# Access a certain button from recyclerview and change it's background image

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to change the background image of a certain button when clicked in a recyclerView. The button's background image is changing properly but also changing the background of the button found in the 8th..16th..etc row as well. (I am currently populating data in the recycler view using a for-loop for testing)

My code is

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final myFirstAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    firstlistitem listItem = listItems.get(position);

    holder.itemView.setTag(position);
    holder.btnBookMark.setTag(position);

    holder.btnBookMark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                 
    holder.btnBookMark.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bookmarkred);
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: so you want to change background of every 8th, then 16th and so on item in your list ?

Comment: No Gautam. I want to only change the background of the button pressed. But this code is changing the background of the button pressed AND the 8th and 16th

Comment: okay. Since recyclerview works by recycling the views, so the view has been changed by you i.e the background color and its getting re-used so you are seeing the same color yet again. So to handle this, either maintain the state using an object or either use mutate() on drawable

Comment: Thank you Guatam for explaining it that way. Makes perfect sense. I will research on how to do that and try it.

Answer (score 1):

The background is changing because, its a RecyclerView and it recyclers the view and reuses it. Hence, when you click on 8th position and scroll to bottom, it is reusing the item at 8 position with custom background for other items. Because of this you are getting custom background for later items on scroll.

If you have many items which will have changed background do this.

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    boolean newBackground = false;
    Button button

    ViewHolder(View itemView){
        ...
        button.setOnClickListner((v) - > newBackground = true);
    }
}
```

Then you can check the value of `newBackground` and set the background in `onBindViewHolder()`

If you have only one item of which the background will change at a time then you can declare a field in the Adapter and check that to change the background.

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>{

    int newBackgroundPos = -1;

    @Override
    public final void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.button.setOnClickListener((v) -> newBackGroundPos = position);

       if(position == newBackgroundPos)
           holder.itemView.setBackground(newBackground);
       else
           holder.itemView.setBackground(normalBackground);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Saran for answering. I will try doing it your way and get back to your answer of course.

Comment: @SinanNoureddine Did you get your expected output?

Comment: I'm afraid your solution didn't work because it gave me an error that lambda expression is not supported at this language level. However i was able to make it work by creating an array with the same size as the list and on every index of the array i check if i change the background or not.

Comment: Just replace the lambda expression ((v) -> newBackGroundPos = position) with `OnClickListener` and then in OnClickListener -> OnClick method just paste this `newBackGroundPos = position`. You got the lambda expression error because its only supported in Java 8 and you must be using 7